# Update existing clustering with new instances

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I have a collection of texts mapped to document vectors.
I want to cluster these to K groups with the following desiderata:

- Use an algorithm other than KMeans.
- Update existing clusters and/or assignments with new incoming data in the future, without clustering from scratch (i.e. split / merge / update existing clusters, wrt some clustering quality criteria)

Is there an approach for this?